# query won't work after pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-order-by

I'm trying to develop a query and i got something like this

```
SELECT a.No,
       a.Finish,
       a.Shift,
       a.McCode,
       d.NAME,
       b.ItemCode,
       b.ItemName,
       b.Qty,
       b.LotNo,
       b.Description,
       CASE
         WHEN b.Description LIKE '%not good%' THEN 'NG'
         ELSE 'OK'
       END                                     AS OKNG,
       c.ItemCode                              AS matcode,
       c.LotNo                                 AS matlot,
       CASE
         WHEN e.GroupName = 'CONTACT' THEN 'CONTACT'
         ELSE 'Coil/Silver/Wire'
       END                                     AS GroupName,
       ( c.Qty / ( a.Qty + a.QtyNg ) ) * b.Qty AS materialused
FROM   PPRDDLV a
       LEFT JOIN ICMUTTRAN b
              ON a.PrdNo = b.TranNo
                 AND a.No = b.TranId
       LEFT JOIN ICMUTTRAN c
              ON a.PrdNo = c.TranNo
                 AND a.Finish = c.DatePost
                 AND c.TranTypeID = 6
                 AND c.LotNo <> '0'
       LEFT JOIN popr d
              ON a.OprCode = d.Code
       LEFT JOIN ICITEM e
              ON c.ItemId = e.id
WHERE  c.qty IS NOT NULL
       AND b.ItemCode IS NOT NULL
```

I got around 49000 records in around 2 seconds, then I wan't to pivot a column that has 2 kind of value, so I turned it to something like this

```
SELECT no,
       finish,
       shift,
       mccode,
       NAME,
       itemcode,
       itemname,
       qty,
       lotno,
       description,
       okng,
       matcode,
       matlot
FROM   (SELECT a.No,
               a.Finish,
               a.Shift,
               a.McCode,
               d.NAME,
               b.ItemCode,
               b.ItemName,
               b.Qty,
               b.LotNo,
               b.Description,
               CASE
                 WHEN b.Description LIKE '%not good%' THEN 'NG'
                 ELSE 'OK'
               END                                     AS OKNG,
               c.ItemCode                              AS matcode,
               c.LotNo                                 AS matlot,
               CASE
                 WHEN e.GroupName = 'CONTACT' THEN 'CONTACT'
                 ELSE 'Coil/Silver/Wire'
               END                                     AS GroupName,
               ( c.Qty / ( a.Qty + a.QtyNg ) ) * b.Qty AS materialused
        FROM   PPRDDLV a
               LEFT JOIN ICMUTTRAN b
                      ON a.PrdNo = b.TranNo
                         AND a.No = b.TranId
               LEFT JOIN ICMUTTRAN c
                      ON a.PrdNo = c.TranNo
                         AND a.Finish = c.DatePost
                         AND c.TranTypeID = 6
                         AND c.LotNo <> '0'
               LEFT JOIN popr d
                      ON a.OprCode = d.Code
               LEFT JOIN ICITEM e
                      ON c.ItemId = e.id
        WHERE  c.qty IS NOT NULL
               AND b.ItemCode IS NOT NULL) AS a
       PIVOT (Max(materialused)
             FOR groupname IN ([CONTACT],
                               [Coil/Silver/Wire])) AS b
```

but the query won't complete even after 10 minutes, it won't even show a single records. beside that one, the first query before I used pivot, I put an order by a.no but when I executed it, the result only shows to record 105 but the query is still working and no more record was loaded.

can anyone help me find out what's going on?
thank you!

Here's the sample data collected from the inner query and the expected value after the query.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI2ns.png)

I realize that I selected "matcode" in the outer select while it shouldn't be there (still didn't work though, and note for the column "material used", I'll be using it later after the pivot is done)

Comment: please post some sample data and expected result

Comment: performance issue in your query so try to avoid left join and use "with(NOLOCK)" table hints in your query.Why this table use " ICMUTTRAN " multiple times?

Comment: @Squirrel can I post just the sample data from the inner query and expected value after the pivot? since I think the inner query was just a normal sql for collecting data.

Comment: @santoshkumarPithani OK I'll look into that function, I'll let you know if it works. And the reason I'm using ICMUTTRAN more than once is because for every row of PPRDDLV have a relation with at least 2 row in ICMUTTRAN with different ItemCode, and I want them to be displayed in 1 row instead of 2

Comment: If you are happy that your first query works in an acceptable time why not wrap it in an outer query which conditionally aggregates to get the 2 columns you want.

Comment: @P.Salmon that's why i use pivot with the first query as the subquery, but it doesn't return any result

Comment: Unless you can be 100% certain that non of the items in (c.Qty / ( a.Qty + a.QtyNg ) ) * b.Qty are null then you should cater for null in each of them. I would also try to ensure that I don't get a surprise divide by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional aggregate instead of pivot.

```
SELECT no,
       finish,
       shift,
       mccode,
       NAME,
       itemcode,
       itemname,
       qty,
       lotno,
       description,
       okng,
       matcode,
       matlot,
       [CONTACT] = Max(CASE WHEN GroupName = 'CONTACT' THEN materialused END),
       [Coil/Silver/Wire] = Max(CASE WHEN GroupName <> 'CONTACT' THEN materialused END)
FROM   (<inner query>) AS a
GROUP  BY no,
          finish,
          shift,
          mccode,
          NAME,
          itemcode,
          itemname,
          qty,
          lotno,
          description,
          okng,
          matcode,
          matlot
```

Comment: It still didn't work, I'm starting to think that the data is the problem but is it possible? or could the column selected in the outer query cause the query to not show any data? (I Just realize i selected something that shouldn't be there, just edited it on my question along with a sample data)

Answer (score 0):

```
---IF you don't have index on filter columns then try to apply for performance  

 SELECT a.No,
       a.Finish,
       a.Shift,
       a.McCode,
       d.NAME,
       b.ItemCode,
       b.ItemName,
       b.Qty,
       b.LotNo,
       b.Description,
        CASE WHEN b.Description LIKE '%not good%' THEN 'NG'
               ELSE 'OK'
              END  AS OKNG,
     c.ItemCode,   
     c.LotNo,   
     MAX(CASE WHEN e.groupname ='CONTACT' THEN    ( c.Qty / ( a.Qty + a.QtyNg ) ) * b.Qty END)OVER(ORDER BY a.no) AS [CONTACT],
       MAX(CASE WHEN e.groupname ='Coil/Silver/Wire' THEN  ( c.Qty / ( a.Qty + a.QtyNg ) ) * b.Qty END)OVER(ORDER BY a.no) AS [Coil/Silver/Wire]
FROM   PPRDDLV a WITH(NOLOCK)
       LEFT JOIN ICMUTTRAN b WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.PrdNo = b.TranNo
                 AND a.No = b.TranId
       LEFT JOIN ICMUTTRAN c WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.PrdNo = c.TranNo
                 AND a.Finish = c.DatePost
                 AND c.TranTypeID = 6
                 AND c.LotNo <> '0'
       LEFT JOIN popr d WITH(NOLOCK)
              ON a.OprCode = d.Code
       LEFT JOIN ICITEM e
              ON c.ItemId = e.id
WHERE  c.qty IS NOT NULL
       AND b.ItemCode IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: it does resulted with all the row I have but all the Qty went to the column of "CONTACT", it took 51 minutes too. I don't actually understand how NOLOCK works but from what I understand is it to enable you to do a query even if the values are being used by another process?